# ERROR: attempted to install release build of official plugin on snapshot build of Elasticsearch

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

After successfull install of elasticsearch using Homebrew, I can't install plugins:

```
voleks@home bin % elasticsearch-plugin install analysis-phonetic
-> Installing analysis-phonetic
-> Failed installing analysis-phonetic
-> Rolling back analysis-phonetic
-> Rolled back analysis-phonetic
ERROR: attempted to install release build of official plugin on snapshot build of Elasticsearch
```

Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems that Homebrew doesn't install release version of elasticsearch. Instead it installs snapshot, but elasticsearch-plugin script installs release version of a plugin. Is there a way to install snapshot version of plugin? How to do that?

UPDATE: As a temporary solution, I manually installed elasticsearch and the plugins

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to the homebrew path for elasticsearch-plugin -> **cd /usr/local/var/homebrew/linked/elasticsearch**
2. After that run this -> sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/analysis-phonetic/analysis-phonetic-7.8.1.zip

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed elasticsearch via homebrew, you can use command `elasticsearch-plugin` directly to install the required plugins.

I also faced the same issue while downloading the plugin by name. I was able to download the plugin via url.

Example:

You can download it using command from anywhere in your terminal

```
elasticsearch-plugin install https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch-plugins/analysis-phonetic/analysis-phonetic-7.10.0.zip
```

Change the plugin version according to your need in above command.